# Latency while accessing cross domain application within iFrame

Tags: javascript, performance, iframe, cross-domain, latency

I've this generic query. When a cross domain content in an iFrame is loaded for the first time within a website, we usually see considerable latency (7-8 seconds) in content load time. Could anyone explain the technicality involved resulting in this latency ?
I understand that for subsequent requests to this domain, the latency is decreased (2-3 seconds) because of browser caching. Also, is there a way to minimize the latency for first time users or is this obvious ?

Comment: Didn't you answer the question yourself: "_because of browser caching_".

Comment: You should include your code if you expect to get helpful answers, however as a rule you will have to have some latency for the first load. In order to do something to help with this please read the following article https://3perf.com/blog/link-rels/